# JMeter - How to use the jQuery (not CSS) extractor

Tags: jquery, jmeter, css-selectors, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

Using jMeter 4.0, I need to extract the value of an element which I cannot identify directly, but I can identify one of its siblings.

I want to use jQuery like so: $("#someId").parent().find(".title")
That is garden variety jQuery: 'get the parent of the element, then within it get the element with the class title'.

This sounds simple enough, but I cant get it to work in jMeter.
All examples/articles I could find about the CSS/jQuery extractor use CSS rather than jQuery.

Is there anything special I should do? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: jQuery selectors *are*, for the most part, just CSS selectors, though...

Answer (score 3):

Actually [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) is an HTML extractor, JMeter supports [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) by default (or [Jodd CSSelly](https://jodd.org/csselly/)) parser which is used for parsing **HTML**

> parses HTML to the same DOM as modern browsers do

The **JQuery/CSS** is actually only the syntax used in the expression

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using a CSS/JQuery selector like syntax
>
> jsoup elements support a CSS (or jquery) like selector syntax to find matching elements

**EDIT**

The name changed in JMeter 5 to <strike>HTML Extractor</strike> CSS Selector Extractor, following an [enhancement](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62593) to avoid confusion